# when i start my emmbedt web server on port 8080 i get windows security alert , can i avoid it?

Tags: windows, security, webserver, embeddedwebserver

is there any way  to avoid this when using embedded web server in windows?
i don't want  users to be scare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you bind to all interfaces and the firewall is enabled, there is no way to avoid this. If your service does not need to be accessed from outside of the computer, you can bind to just `localhost` which should avoid the firewall warning.